# php-activerecord is not working in PHP 8.2 with Codeignitor

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

We developed a CodeIgniter application using the `PHP ActiveRecord ORM` for the Query builder, and the application runs in a Docker container on an AWS server.

We recently upgraded PHP from version 8.0 to version 8.2 and php-activerecord is no longer supported by PHP 8.2. The application crashes with a `Bad Gateway` error.

Is it possible to modify php-activerecord to make it run and what steps should I take to fix the bad gateway error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last release of [php-activerecord](https://www.phpactiverecord.org/) was almost 15 years ago. So it's quite normal that it no longer gets along with PHP 8.2.

That said, another [PHP ActiveRecord](https://github.com/php-activerecord/activerecord) project exists and is designed for PHP 8.1+. I don't know if it will require a migration effort for you. You should have a look on it.